# order by all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I just wanted to order the list of candidates by their partylist and position. I used OR Clause but it work, doesnt support many columns. this is my code: Help me please. Thanks

```sql
SELECT student.firstname, 
       candidates.partylist, 
       candidates.position 
FROM   student 
       INNER JOIN candidates 
               ON student.student_id = candidates.student_id 
ORDER  BY partylist, 
          position = 'President' 
           OR position = 'VicePresident' 
           OR position = 'Secretary' 
           OR position = 'Treasurer' 
           OR position = 'Auditor';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need `Case` in `Order by` instead of `OR` conditions.

Try something like this

```sql
SELECT student.firstname, 
       candidates.partylist, 
       candidates.position 
FROM   student 
       INNER JOIN candidates 
               ON student.student_id = candidates.student_id 
ORDER  BY partylist, 
          CASE position 
            WHEN 'President' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'VicePresident' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'Secretary' THEN 3 
            WHEN 'Treasurer' THEN 4 
            WHEN 'Auditor' THEN 5 
            ELSE 6  -- Here replace 6 with 0
          END
```

**Note :** If you want to the data other than the mention list in `Order by` to come first then replace `6` with `0`.

Comment: This helps me a lot. :) God Bless you.

Comment: @FemaMaeGadgodeSantos Instead of sending your blessings all over the place you might want to read  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Its my fist time tho i dont even know how. but good thing you told me about it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**FIELD**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) instead:

```sql
SELECT student.firstname, candidates.partylist, candidates.position 
FROM student 
INNER JOIN candidates ON student.student_id = candidates.student_id 
ORDER BY partylist, 
         FIELD(position, 'President', 'VicePresident', 'Secretary', 
               'Treasurer', 'Auditor');
```

Comment: This helps me a lot.  :) God Bless you.

Comment: in GiorgosBetsos query others will be the first, in the VR46 - the last )